# Applescript getting definitions from google

Tags: applescript

in google, you can do "define:cat" and it will give you a list of definitions.

Does anyone know how to get the definitions of a word with applescript from google?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough and tumble, but it works...

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acat"}
    set theDocument to document 1
    set theSource to source of theDocument -- result: source code for the page.
end tell
```

Note that the search term can be tacked onto the end after the delimiter `%3A`. From there, you'll have to scrape what you want from the page, but that's icky in even the best of languages.

Comment: Oh ok. For some reason it's not giving me the correct source. It says in the source that's the page is forbidden. Weird. Happens when I curl it too. Any ideas?

Comment: @Elijah W., this worked perfectly for me. Did you try the simple example?